# Keep Leap Motion tracking when program in not in focus

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tracking, leap-motion

I am using Visual Studio and the motion leap and want to track the users hands even when the user is looking and another program and the leap's program is not in focus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive tracking data when your application is in the background, you need to set the background frames policy flag. On the user side, the “Allow Background Apps” checkbox must be enabled in the Leap Motion Control Panel or this policy will be denied.

```
controller.setPolicy(Leap::Controller::POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
```

Source: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/api/Leap.Controller.html